# Sample size determination for wilcoxon rank sum

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, sample-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

When calculating a nonparametric test, you don't have to make any assumption about the distribution of the values; but if you want to calculate necessary sample size for a study to be analyzed by a nonparametric test, you must make an assumption about the distribution of the values.

My data sample has a mass at 0 and some sort of continous distribution. The data represent revenue.

I evaluate the hypothetical medians with Wilcoxon rank sum test.

Is there a way in R to somehow calculate a sample size?

A rule of thumb could be something like - transform the data in a way to be able to do a test on proportions (if 0, then flag as 0; 1 otherwise) and add 20% to the estimated sample size for pvalue = 0.05 and power 80%?

Is there any other way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Try look into [this article](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/004017005000000193), first page formula (3).

Comment: I don't have any university institution access and consulting the paper is ~40 euro for 24 hours... do you know any free access source for this? @Penguin_Knight

Comment: Wow, that's high. I got that reference from the book "Sample Size Determination and Power" by Thomas Ryan. Do you have access to this title?

Comment: I am looking at sever procedures. It turnes out that `power.t.test(delta=0.5, power=0.9)` does work for wilcoxon rank sum test. The think is that my dataset is extremely skewed (the mass at zero consists of 95% of observations). The sample size must be extremely high. I looked into [here](http://www.math.smith.edu/sasr/excerpt-6-1.pdf). I think a two part model procedure is more appropriate. I don't know where to start... I would like then apply a test with some sort of "proportion test" for the part at 0 and then a wilcoxon rank sum test for the continous part.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight what I am doing practically right now is to calculate the 0 / non 0 part sample size with a t-test and add an arbitrary 20%...